# How to stop formatting after using mathematic characters

Tags: math-mode, spacing, equations, formatting

I'm writing a scientific text and need to use β as a character. However when I use `\beta` it changes the formatting of the rest of the paragraph to italics and removes spaces. Is there a way to stop this from happening?

Comment: Welcome! Instead of `\beta` and ignoring errors use `$\beta$`. Mathematical characters want to be typeset in math mode, and `$` switches back and forth between text and math mode (but `$$` does something else and should not be used in LaTeX documents).

Comment: If you don't need `\beta` as a math mode variable but as a normal character in text, then you should use `\usepackage{textgreek}` and then `\textbeta` (or another approach to get Greek letters as characters).